# 2 Summations expressed by single loop in programming is possible. Is that possible in Math to do so?

Tags: summation, notation, programming

Suppose there are two summations.

1)$\sum_{i=1}^5a_i = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2+ 2 = 10$

If $a$ is constant, has value 2.

2) $\sum_{i=1}^5b_i = b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3+ 3 = 15$

If $b$ is constant, has value 3.

Now in programming we can do this.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    a += 2;
    b += 3;
}
```

Then at the end of the loop $a = 10$ and $b = 15$. There is no need to write separate loop for both variables.

According my understanding summation behaves as loop. By keeping above programming loop in mind where we can use single loop for 2 different summations because looping condition is same, Is there any way we could do this to summation $\sum_{i=1}^5a_i$ and summation $\sum_{i=1}^5b_i$ by merging them into single summation based on condition. In other words describing 2 different summations by one summation because both summations have same condition.

Comment: This may be an interesting reading [Is Sigma Σ a mathematical way of doing a for loop?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694311/is-sigma-sigma-a-mathematical-way-of-doing-a-for-loop), loop and sum is not really the same...

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful.

Comment: By the way if by merge you mean "adding both sums", you can write something like $\sum_{i=1}^5a_i + \sum_{i=1}^5b_i = \sum_{i=1}^5(a_i+b_i)$, but from your question it feels more like you just want to express two sums simultaneously, expressing two sums by writing the common stuff only once (lower and upper bound), I don't know about a way to do this in math (and frankly I don't see a use for that).

Comment: "express two sums simultaneously" exactly what I am trying to do. Because I have very lengthy analytical models of time and energy of censer network. Both models are replicas of each other but have different variables and have same summation condition. I was thinking that is that possible to describe them with single summation? Instead of writing same summation for both of them separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing the sum $(a,b)$ as an ordered pair, you have

$(a,b)=\sum_{i=1}^5 (a_i,b_i)$

Comment: is $(\sum_{i=1}^5 (a_i), \sum_{i=1}^5 (b_i))  = \sum_{i=1}^5 (a_i,b_i)$ ? Are you suggesting if we take both summations as set then we can do this?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When the ordered pairs $(a_i,b_i)$ are summed, each component is summed separately.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, in both math and programming, is to declare a function, e.g., $$f(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^5 n = 5n.$$ Then, whenever you need that function, you just "call" it, and you can even nest calls, e.g., $f(f(a) f(b)) + 1$.

At the same time we need to remind ourselves that math and programming are different things.

When publishing a math paper, you want other human beings to understand your mathematical thoughts and deem them elegant; if a computer understands, that's just an added bonus. When publishing the source code of a computer program, you obviously still want other humans to understand your thinking, but the main goal is something that a computer can run in an efficient manner. Even if it's just shaving off a few milliseconds off the benchmark.